# Hypothesis most-powerful test, exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I have following problem to solve:

**General population has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. A six-element sample was drawn from it: $ 3.2 ; 2.5 ; 0.1 ; 5.1; 4.7; 4.1$. Using the most-powerful test verify zero-hypothesis, that $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ against alternative hypothesis, that $\lambda=\frac{1}{3}$. Assume significance level $ \alpha=0,05$.**

What I tried :

If I'm not mistaken, to find most-powerful test, I must solve $$\frac{L_{1}}{L_{0}}>c$$ where $c$ is some constant, and fraction on the left side represents likelihood functions, presented as products of the values of density functions for $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}$ . So I tried :

$$ \frac{ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{3}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{3}x_{i}}}{ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_{i}}} > c$$

$$\frac{\left( \frac{1}{3}\right) ^n \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}} }{\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) ^n \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}} > c$$

$$\left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{6} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}} >c  $$
I log both sides
$$n\cdot \log\frac{2}{3}+\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}}{6n} > c_{1}$$ where $c_{1} = \log c$.
After few more modifications I finally have
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} > c_{2}$$ where $$c_{2} = 6\cdot \left( c_{1}-n\cdot\log\frac{2}{3}\right) $$

If $\alpha=0,05$, that means $P\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} > c_{2} | \lambda=\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0,05 $ (right?)

And now I don't know what to do next. How to find $c_{2}$ constant? If general population were normally distributed, maybe I could standarize it somehow. With exponential distribution I have no idea what to do. Maybe I do something wrong, or don't know about something? I will be thankful for answers.
(Forgive me my English, I'm not native speaker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now let's suppose we have to calculate the power of this test.

Starting from the Decision rule that is to reject $H_0$ if $Y=\sum_i X_i>21.3$ the power is defined as follows

$$\gamma=\mathbb{P}[Y>21.3|\lambda=1/3]$$

Now

$$Y\sim \text{Gamma}[6;1/3]$$

thus with a simple transformation we get

$$W=\frac{2}{3}Y\sim \text{Gamma}[6;1/2]=\chi_{(12)}^2$$

and now you can proceed as in the previous case.

To understand these transformation use the usual technics you surely know for monotonic transformations of univariate rv's

$$\gamma=\mathbb{P}[W>14.2]\approx 28.81\%$$

To calculate this probability the table I showed you is not detailed enough. You can use a more detailed one or a calculator.

Comment: Very nice, thank you once more. By the way, wikipedia shows (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Related_distributions) that it should be $Gamma(6,2)$, right?

Comment: @FermatFan; both results are correct. It depends if you consider the second Gamma parameter as the "scale" or "rate" parameter. I considered it a "rate" parameter, and I did that following your definition of Exponential density....in other words I did the same as you did...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Correct. Now you have, Setting $Y=\sum_i X_i$,

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>c_2|\lambda=0.5]=0.05$$

But the distribution of $Y$ under $H_0$ is a known distribution:

$$Y\sim \text{Gamma}\left(6;\frac{1}{2}\right)=\chi_{(12)}^2$$

...and you can read the result on that table

[image]

and being the sum of your observation $=19.7<21.03$ you **cannot Reject** $H_0$

Comment: Wow, thank you! It helped me a lot. But now I have two questions :

1) Maybe it is a silly question, but anyway I will ask : why Y has a Gamma distribution?

2) How do we know that $\Gamma(6,\frac{1}{2})$ is equal to $χ2_{(12)}$?

Comment: @FermatFan ; 1) The sum of $n$ i.i.d. Negative exponential rv's is a Gamma distribution. You can easy prove it by using MGF of  Characteristic function

2) $\chi_{(n)}^2$ is a particular case of gamma distribution: it is a $\text{Gamma}\left[\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2} \right]$. This can be easy proved with a simple rv's transformation

Comment: Okay, I will do this work. Thanks a lot.

And last questions : You wrote that chi-squared distribution is a case of Gamma distribution with parameters $[\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}]$. So if $\lambda$ in $H_0$ had a value other than $\frac{1}{2}$, what would I do then? And what is the role of $\lambda=\frac{1}{3}$ in $H_{1}$?

Comment: @FermatFan : nice question. In this case you have to transform you  rv in order to get again a chi - square distribution. I will get a new answer with a natural follow up of this exercise...